# Convert BigInteger to Shorter String in Java

Tags: java, string, biginteger

I'm looking for a way to convert a BigInteger into a very short String (shortest possible). The conversion needs to be reversible. The security of the conversion is not a big deal in this case. Would anyone have recommendations or samples of how they would go about solving this problem?

Comment: "hashing" and "reversible" doesn't match. A hash isn't reversible by design! What you're looking for is probably compression.

Comment: Thanks Joachin. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One easy way is to use `BigInteger.toString(Character.MAX_RADIX)`. To reverse, use the following constructor: `BigInteger(String val, int radix)`.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about the `Character.MAX_RADIX`.

Comment: MAX_RADIX is 36: from 0-9a-z. But you can use also uppercase chars using Base64 or Base62 if you want to have only alphanumeric characters, this class does the trick: https://github.com/opencoinage/opencoinage/blob/master/src/java/org/opencoinage/util/Base62.java

Answer (score 9):

You can use a Base64 encoding. Note that this example uses Apache commons-codec:

```
BigInteger number = new BigInteger("4143222334431546643677890898767548679452");
System.out.println(number);

String encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(number.toByteArray()));
System.out.println(encoded);

BigInteger decoded = new BigInteger(Base64.decodeBase64(encoded));
System.out.println(decoded);
```

prints:

```
4143222334431546643677890898767548679452
DC0DmJRYaAn2AVdEZMvmhRw=
4143222334431546643677890898767548679452
```

Comment: the "=" (or "==") at the end can be stripped out, as it is just padding, and the decoding works fine.