# Is it possible to insert letters into an int?

Tags: java, mysql, string, type-conversion, integer

I'm confused, I was asked to do a connection from Java into MySQL using OOP and DAO, but my professor asked us to do it in a the following way:

We need to make the variable "MethodOfPayment" as an int in Java and as a char in MySQL table, and we need to write the method of payment depending on the number you put in Java. For example:

Java: MethodOfPayment: (you write) 1 will insert "Credit card" in MySQL
Java: MethodOfPayment: (you write) 2 will insert "Debit card" in MySQL
but using the int MethodOfPayment variable.

I tried a switch, but it won't let me convert the int "With" letters to string, I don't even know if it's possible.

This is the insert I have in the DAO method class

```
private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO Client(Name, LastName, MethodOfPayment ) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

I do it with ResultSet, ArrayList, PreparedStatement with a JDBC connection to MySQL.

```
public static int = MethodOfPayment;
```

This is the variable that will write on the database an the one my professor is asking us to keep as an int in java and write the char on MySQL.

This is the method I'm trying to convert the int to string, but obviously crashes because the letters inside the int. I don't know if it's possible or my professor is wrong.

```java
public static void PaymentMethod() {
    int MethodSelection; //this is a variable to select the method in the switch and assign the values to the main variable of the payment

    System.out.println("Insert Payment Method");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    MethodSelection = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    switch (MethodSelection) {
        case 1:
            MethodOfPayment = Integer.parseInt("Debit");
            
            break;
        case 2:
            MethodOfPayment = Integer.parseInt("Credit Card");
            
            break;//  ...

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Method, Try Again");
            PaymentMethod(); // I don't know a way to restart the switch without restarting the whole method when another value is inserted
    }
}
```

DAOmethod:

Person is the father clas with, name and Last name. I get TypeOfPayment from a son class that has get, set and stringbuilder with the super to get the person data

```
public int insert(Client person){
    Connection conn =  null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    
    int registros = 0;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
        
        stmt.setString(1, person.getStr_Name());
        stmt.setString(2, person.getStr_Lastname);
        stmt.setInt(3, person.getInt_TypeOfPayment());
        
        
        
        
        archives= stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }finally{
        try {
            close(stmt);
            close(conn);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
    return archives;       
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you've declared `MethodOfPayment`, but if you have it as a `String`, not an `int`, then you  don't need the `Integer.parseInt` calls after the `switch`.

Comment: parseInt method don't convert any string to number. The string should be a number in double quotes. like "123", Then only it will give convert and give you a number. Don't parse the string, instead of that based on MethodSelection value assign a integer value to MethodOfPayment. 
One more question. Are you using simple jdbc with resultset or hibernate to communicate with data base?

Comment: Srry i have it as global, ill correct the question with it, but the thing is that I don't know how to write letters in the int variable, it crashes, I don't know if its possible to convert it so I can write the word "debit" in the database using that int variable

Comment: @Sahm did your professor mention what values should be passed in query? is it int value like 1 or String like debit ?

Comment: he said that the variable in java has to be int, so in the selection, we enter a number, but using that same variable, we write the type of payment in MySQL, the word "debit" for example would appear in the MySQL table if we press 1 using the int variable for both activities, I know is confusing I'm sorry Ive been looking for hours and cant find a solution

Comment: I think you need to ask your professor to clarify what they mean, when they ask you to store the word `"Debit"` in an integer.  Integers can only store numbers, not text.

Comment: Your professor did not ask you to store `Debit` or `Credit card` in an `int`  variable. They asked you to store `Credit card` or `Debit card` **in the database** when the variable in Java has value 1, respectively 2.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your program. Java naming conventions for variable is lowerCamelCase, happy learning!

```
package test1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Snippet {
    public static void PaymentMethod() {
        int methodSelectionInt;// this is a variable to select the method in the swich and asign the values to
                                // the main variable of the payment
        String methodOfPayment;// the database variable of the payment
        Boolean tryAgain = false;
        while (tryAgain) { 
            
            System.out.println("Insert Payment Method");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            methodSelectionInt = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            switch (methodSelectionInt) {
            case 1:
                methodOfPayment = "Debit";
                tryAgain = false; 
                break;
            case 2:
                methodOfPayment = "Credit Card";
                tryAgain = false; 
                break;// ...
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Method, Try Again");
                tryAgain = true; // 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is, my professor is asking me to use the variable that will write on the database (MethodOfPayment) as an int, he won't allow us to use it as a string, so I think I need to write the words on the int  variable literally, that's whats driving me crazy (also thanks for the switch)

Comment: @Sahm you may have to use 

// convert to big integer
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(text.getBytes());
System.out.println(bigInt.toString());
// convert back
String textBack = new String(bigInt.toByteArray());
System.out.println("And back = " + textBack);

Comment: I am almost 100% sure there is a communication gap between professor. But as you have asked here is an example of how to convert string to bigInt vice versa. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501964/3651739

Comment: @Sahm what is you DAO method name? can you comment DAO class name, method name with parameter?

Comment: its up, im sorry for not replying I'm trying your method but don't seem to get it right, also, I'm sorry if I don't know how to make my self clear, its my first year in this thank you a lot for your help and patience

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. if you are using Hibernate you can do it with @Type annotation
2. If you are using JPA then you can do it with convert. It is simpler among all.
3. If you are using simple JDBC and not using entity mapping, then while saving before executing query set parameters as debit, credit based on number entered by user. For example:

   ```
   stmt.setString(3, person.getInt_TypeOfPayment() == 2 ? "debit" : "credit" );
   ```

While retrieving data, iterate over result set and set value as int based on the string which comes from data base. Sample code as follows.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
while(rs.next()){
    ....
    int payment = rs.getString("your column name / index") == "debit" ? 2 : 1;
    person.setIntTypeOfPayment(payment);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to **convert char to int in Java** use one of the methods:

- Implicit type casting //getting ASCII values
- Character.getNumericValue()
- Integer.parseInt() //in pair with
- Subtracting ‘0’ //works for integer numeric values only

You can also do explicit type casting. However, this is a redundant operation: it is not needed, but just works in Java.

Answer (score -1):

you can use an Ints method from the **Guava library**, which in combination with Java 8's Optional, makes for a powerful and concise way to convert a **string into an int**:

```
 import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

 public static void PaymentMethod() {

     int MethodSelection;//this is a variable to select the method in the swich and asign the values to the main variable of the payment

     System.out.println("Insert Payment Method");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     MethodSelection = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
     switch (MethodSelection) {
         case 1:
             MethodOfPayment = Optional.ofNullable("Debit").map(Ints::tryParse).orElse(0);
             break;

         case 2:
             MethodOfPayment = Optional.ofNullable("Credit Card").map(Ints::tryParse).orElse(0);
             break;

         default:
             System.out.println("Invalid Method, Try Again");
             PaymentMethod();
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Consider using concatenation (" string " + variable + " string "), or using a StringBuilder. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Im using a string builder but the thing is, I need to give the int variable the value of the word "Debit" to insert it into the database if I'm correct, so by trying to write letters on the int, it crashes, I don't know what to do