# How to turn Binary String into text?

Tags: java, string, binary, biginteger

I am working on a personal project. I want to create an encryption program that lets you encrypt, and decrypt a String using a key. Almost finished only need help with the final part. I want to convert a binary String into a text.
Let's say the binary outcome(which I want to convert into a normal text) is:

```
01001000011000010110100001100001
```

This converted into text is "Haha".

NOTE: I am only working with BigIntegers since Almost every number I am using is too big for a normal Integer.

**EDIT: Found the answer using this this code:**

```
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0;i < input.length();i += 8) {
  output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i, i + 8), 2));
}
       System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java

Comment: @BipBip Doesn't help since I am working with BigIntegers. And they are working with ints.

Comment: @fihdi You can take reference from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716830/convert-biginteger-to-shorter-string-in-java/5717191#5717191

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh This seems to work, can you also do this with Base36? Because I am using base 36 right now.

Comment: `input.substring`? How is this BigInteger?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so it can help others

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it in one line:

```
String str = "01001000011000010110100001100001";

String decoded = Arrays.stream(str.split("(?<=\\G.{8})"))
    .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s, 2))
    .map(i -> "" + Character.valueOf((char)i.intValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("")); // "Haha"
```

It can probably be made prettier, but I didn't have an IDE handy (just thumbed it in on my phone).

You'll note that `BigInteger` isn't needed, and this code handles input of arbitrarily large length.